# Kafka connect JDBC connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector in bulk mode using the query .

```
query = select name, cast(ID as NUMBER(20,2)),status from table_name
```

Is this possible?
If possible am I missing something?
I am getting

```
exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:148)
org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal character in: CAST(IDASNUMBER(20,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an alias for the 2nd column. This alias must be the name of the target avro-field.